# SAX printing conditions

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

Is there a method in order to print with Java SAX only the "addr" value if the previous element has "up" as value for the "state" attribute in the "status" element ?

The XML is like this

```
<host starttime="11111" endtime="2222">
    <status state="up" reason="4"/>
    <address addr="ABC123" addrtype="1" />
    <address addr="AAA" addrtype="BBB" vendor="231" />
</host>

<host>
    <status state="down" reason="no"/>
    <address addr="ZXC567" addrtype="3" />
</host>
```

And I need to print the string ABC123 (the value of the "addr" attribute) only if the "state" value is "up".

The portion of the Java SAX code that I'm using to do this is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
    parser.parse(new File("/tmp/test1"), new DefaultHandler() {

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equals("status")) {
                if (atts.getValue(0).contains("up")) {
                    System.out.println("status= " + atts.getValue(0));
                }
```

Comment: You missed some brackets in your example...

Comment: Sure; use a boolean variable in your handler to keep the state from the status element.

Comment: Yeah! thanks  qqilihq the boolean worked!